# CISpotLight filter and nil results

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image

I'm trying to achieve spotlight effect. I've written some code basing on
[the Apple CoreImageFilterReference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000136-DontLinkElementID_144) however it seems to not work. `filter` object is `nil` (obviously `outputImage`, `newImage` are `nil` too), but `ciImage` is ok.

```
CIVector *inputLightPointsAt = [CIVector vectorWithX:20.f Y:20.f Z:5.f];
CIColor *inputColor = [[CIColor alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor redColor]];
CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"].CGImage];

CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISpotLight" keysAndValues:
                                            kCIInputImageKey, ciImage,
                                            @"inputBrightness", @1.5f,
                                            @"inputConcentration", @0.5f,
                                            @"inputColor", inputColor,
                                            @"inputLightPosition", inputLightPointsAt,
                                            @"inputLightPointsAt", inputLightPointsAt,
                                            nil];
CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:outputImage];
```

Anybody has any idea what am I doing wrong? How to make it working?

BTW: When I changed the filter to something else like sepia etc - everything was working fine.

```
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone" keysAndValues:
                        kCIInputImageKey, ciImage,
                        @"inputIntensity", @0.8,
                        nil];
```

Comment: @MidhunMP Well, when I print `ciImage` I get `<CIImage: 0x109540340 extent [0 0 900 1350]>` so it surely isn't nil. I've also added `CoreImage` framework to the workspace and imported it in the class. Any other idea :/? Also please see my edit, after changing the filter output and filter is not nil. If `ciImage` would be the problem, both filters would result with nil.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As far as I can see in your tags, your target is iOS and according to the documentation:

```
Availability
Available in OS X v10.4 and later.
```

it is not available on iOS.

Comment: This is wrong info. Here I found from Apple documentation: Available in OS X v10.4 and later and in iOS 9 and later.

Comment: @AbdulYasin In 15th of July 2014 the newest system was iOS 7.x. On September 18, 2014 Apple released iOS 8. They added support for CISpotLight effect from iOS9 (2016). More than 3 years ago answer was correct. Now it isn't. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this as a late answer in case someone might get help from this.

Actually for Spotlight filter is little tricky. You need to set its Point to position light carefully.

```
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISpotLight")
        filter?.setDefaults()
        filter?.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter?.setValue(CIVector(x: inputImage!.extent.size.width/2, y: inputImage!.extent.size.height/2, z: 60), forKey: "inputLightPointsAt")
        filter?.setValue(2.5, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey)
        filter?.setValue(0.1, forKey: "inputConcentration")
        outputImage = filter?.outputImage
```

Here i am passing input image and getting the output image after applying the filter.

Answer (score 1):

It's little bit hard to control light position and focus area but it works well when you understand logic of this filter.

The parameter called `"inputLightPosition"` this will control position of spot projector and `"inputLightPointsAt"` parameter is for controlling light focus position, both of them using CIVector(x,y,z) 3D. `x` should be max input image width and `y` should be max input image height, `z` is also used for distance of spot projector from the image.

For example we can use it with pan gesture to control positions, first create enum for separate control light position and light point called mode and struct for storing all positions then allow selecting mode with buttons and call filter with gesture changed. I tried with 7 sliders to control parameters with this code:

```
struct Spotlight {
  var posiX1: CGFloat = .zero
  var posiY1: CGFloat = .zero
  var posiZ1: CGFloat = .zero
  var posiX2: CGFloat = .zero
  var posiY2: CGFloat = .zero
  var posiZ2: CGFloat = .zero
  var lightColor: UIColor = .yellow
  var brightness: CGFloat = 1.0
  var concentration: CGFloat = 0.1
}

public enum EffectType: String {
    case SpotLight = "CISpotLight"
}

private func getCoreImage() -> CIImage? {
    return CIImage(image: self.inputImage)
}

private func adjustSpotlightFilterWith(spotlight: Spotlight) {
    // Create a filter
    let filter = CIFilter(name: EffectType.SpotLight.rawValue)
    // Create core image and assign it to filter as input image
    let coreImage = getCoreImage()
    filter?.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    // Here adjust spot projector positions
    filter?.setValue(CIVector(x: spotlight.posiX1, y: spotlight.posiY1, z: spotlight.posiZ1), forKey: "inputLightPosition")
    // And here direction of light
    filter?.setValue(CIVector(x: spotlight.posiX2, y: spotlight.posiY2, z: spotlight.posiZ2), forKey: "inputLightPointsAt")
    filter?.setValue(spotlight.brightness, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey)
    // This parameter used for size of the spotlight.
    filter?.setValue(spotlight.concentration[![enter image description here][1]][1], forKey: "inputConcentration")
    // Change color of light with this parameter 
    filter?.setValue(CIColor(cgColor: spotlight.lightColor.cgColor), forKey: kCIInputColorKey)
    guard let outputImage = filter?.outputImage else {
        print("Cannot get 'outputImage' from filter!")
        return
    }
    let context = CIContext(mtlDevice: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!)
    guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) else {
        print("Cannot convert 'outputImage' to core graphic image!")
        return
    }
    // The image will be reversed thats why you can rotate it as you want
    let finalImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: originalImage.scale, orientation: .upMirrored)
    // Use your result image
    mainImageView.image = finalImage
}



@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let value = CGFloat(sender.value)
    switch sender.tag {
    case 0:
        spotlight.posiX1 = value
        break
    case 1:
        spotlight.posiY1 = value
        break
    case 2:
        spotlight.posiZ1 = value
        break
    case 3:
        spotlight.posiX2 = value
        break
    case 4:
        spotlight.posiX2 = value
        break
    case 5:
        spotlight.posiZ1 = value
        break
    case 6:
        spotlight.brightness = value
    case 7:
        spotlight.consantration = value
        break
    default:
        break
    }
    
    adjustSpotlightFilterWith(spotlight: spotlight)
}
```

Screenshot:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiQNf.jpg